# How to show form input fields based on select value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I know this is simple, and I need to search in Google. I tried my best and I could not find a better solution. I have a form field, which takes some input and a select field, which has some values. It also has "Other" value.

What I want is:

If the user selects the 'Other' option, a text field to specify that 'Other' should be displayed. When a user selects another option (than 'Other') I want to hide it again. How can I perform that using JQuery?

This is my JSP code

```
<label for="db">Choose type</label>
<select name="dbType" id=dbType">
   <option>Choose Database Type</option>
   <option value="oracle">Oracle</option>
   <option value="mssql">MS SQL</option>
   <option value="mysql">MySQL</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<div id="otherType" style="display:none;">
  <label for="specify">Specify</label>
  <input type="text" name="specify" placeholder="Specify Databse Type"/>
</div>
```

Now I want to show the DIV tag**(id="otherType")** only when the user selects Other.
I want to try JQuery. This is the code I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="jquery-ui-1.10.0/tests/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.0/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>    
$('#dbType').change(function(){

   selection = $('this').value();
   switch(selection)
   {
       case 'other':
           $('#otherType').show();
           break;
       case 'default':
           $('#otherType').hide();
           break;
   }
});
</script>
```

But I am not able to get this. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: This solution works pretty well too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29321711/5925104

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code:

1. you are missing an open quote on the id of the select element, so: `<select name="dbType" id=dbType">`

should be `<select name="dbType" id="dbType">`

2. `$('this')` should be `$(this)`: there is no need for the quotes inside the paranthesis.
3. use .val() instead of .value() when you want to retrieve the value of an option
4. when u initialize "selection" do it with a var in front of it, unless you already have done it at the beggining of the function

try this:

```
   $('#dbType').on('change',function(){
        if( $(this).val()==="other"){
        $("#otherType").show()
        }
        else{
        $("#otherType").hide()
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ks6cv/

**UPDATE** for use with switch:

```
$('#dbType').on('change',function(){
     var selection = $(this).val();
    switch(selection){
    case "other":
    $("#otherType").show()
   break;
    default:
    $("#otherType").hide()
    }
});
```

**UPDATE** with links for jQuery and jQuery-UI:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>‌​
```

Comment: Still I am not able to get. I am asking, whether this problem is with this?

`<script type="text/javascript"
    src="jquery-ui-1.10.0/tests/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.0/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>`
Can you give the online JQuery link? I need to check whether it works. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**[Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/p9cxd7d1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); // call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
    // this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of our other field changes
    $("#dbType").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});
// this toggles the visibility of other server
function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#dbType").val() === "other")
        $("#otherServer").show();
    else
        $("#otherServer").hide();
}
```

HTML:

```
    <p>Choose type</p>
    <p>Server:
        <select id="dbType" name="dbType">
          <option>Choose Database Type</option>
          <option value="oracle">Oracle</option>
          <option value="mssql">MS SQL</option>
          <option value="mysql">MySQL</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <div id="otherServer">
        <p>Server:
            <input type="text" name="server_name" />
        </p>
        <p>Port:
            <input type="text" name="port_no" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <p align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
    </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `val()` instead of `value()` and you have missed starting quote  `id=dbType"` should be `id="dbType"`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vyc7N/57/)**

*Change*

```
selection = $('this').value();
```

*To*

```
selection = $(this).val();
```

or

```
selection = this.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I got its answer. Here is my code

```
<label for="db">Choose type</label>
<select name="dbType" id=dbType">
   <option>Choose Database Type</option>
   <option value="oracle">Oracle</option>
   <option value="mssql">MS SQL</option>
   <option value="mysql">MySQL</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<div id="other" class="selectDBType" style="display:none;">
<label for="specify">Specify</label>
<input type="text" name="specify" placeholder="Specify Databse Type"/>
</div>
```

And my script is

```
$(function() {

        $('#dbType').change(function() {
            $('.selectDBType').slideUp("slow");
            $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("slow");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function myfun(){
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#select").click(
    function(){
    var data=$("#select").val();
        $("#disp").val(data);
                     });
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>id <input type="text" name="user" id="disp"></p>

<select id="select" onclick="myfun()">
<option name="1"value="1">first</option>
<option name="2"value="2">second</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dbType').change(function(){

   var selection = $(this).val();
   if(selection == 'other')
   {
      $('#otherType').show();
   }
   else
   {
      $('#otherType').hide();
   } 

});
```