# Show hide fields based on multiple select option by jquery

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have these three select boxes below, I want when first select box empty, hide second and third select boxes, When first select box contains `custom-category` show second select box, When first select box contains `custom-tag` show third select box, When first select box contains `custom-category` and `custom-tag` in same time show second and third select boxes

I try to this jquery code but not work for all case that described above

```
$('.field-content-multiple select').change(function() {
$(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('value') == 'custom-category') {
        $('p.field-custom-category').show();
        $('p.field-custom-tag').hide();
    } else if($(this).attr('value') == 'custom-tag') {
        $('p.field-custom-tag').show();
        $('p.field-custom-category').hide();
    } else {
        $('p.field-custom-category').hide();
        $('p.field-custom-tag').hide();
    }
});
}).change();
```

these are the three select boxes

```
<p class="field-content-multiple description description-wide">
<select name="menu-item-content-multiple[<?php echo $item_id; ?>][]" id="edit-menu-item-content-multiple-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-content-multiple bsnselect" multiple>
        <?php foreach (self::$YPE_multiple as $key => $value): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"  <?php echo  selected(in_array($key, $item->content_multiple)); ?>><?php echo $value;?>  </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
</p>

<p class="field-custom-category description description-wide">
<label for="edit-menu-item-custom-category-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Select specific categories' ); ?><br />
    <select name="menu-item-custom-category[<?php echo $item_id; ?>][]" id="edit-menu-item-custom-category-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-custom-category bsnselect" multiple>
        <?php
            $YPE_cats = get_categories();
            foreach ($YPE_cats as $YPE_cat) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $YPE_cat->slug; ?>"  <?php echo  selected(in_array($YPE_cat->slug, $item->custom_category)); ?>><?php echo  $YPE_cat->name;?></option><?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</label>
</p>

<p class="field-custom-tag description description-wide">
<label for="edit-menu-item-custom-tag-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Select specific tags' ); ?><br />
    <select name="menu-item-custom-tag[<?php echo $item_id; ?>][]" id="edit- menu-item-custom-tag-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu- item-custom-tag bsnselect" multiple>
        <?php
            $YPE_tags = get_tags();
            foreach ($YPE_tags as $YPE_tag) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $YPE_tag->slug; ?>" <?php echo  selected(in_array($YPE_tag->slug, $item->custom_tag)); ?>><?php echo $YPE_tag->name;?></option><?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</label>
</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show form input fields based on select value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566999/how-to-show-form-input-fields-based-on-select-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i missunderstood your code in the first comment, the problem is that when you read the "tag" you will hide the "category" and the other way around, this might not be the best work around to the problem, but might help you understand the problem there!

```
var categoryFlag = false;
var tagFlag = false;

$(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('value') == 'custom-category') {
       categoryFlag = true;
    } else if($(this).attr('value') == 'custom-tag') {
       tagFlag = true;
    }
});

if(categoryFlag && tagFlag) {
    $('p.field-custom-category').show();
    $('p.field-custom-tag').show();   
    categoryFlag = false;
    tagFlag = false;
} else if(categoryFlag && !tagFlag) {
    $('p.field-custom-category').show();
    $('p.field-custom-tag').hide();
    categoryFlag = false;
    tagFlag = false;
} else if(!categoryFlag && tagFlag) {
    $('p.field-custom-category').hide();
    $('p.field-custom-tag').show();
    categoryFlag = false;
    tagFlag = false;
} else {
    $('p.field-custom-category').hide();
    $('p.field-custom-tag').hide();
    categoryFlag = false;
    tagFlag = false;
}
```

Comment: I use the [Select2](https://select2.github.io) jquery plugin for select boxes for example when only I select `custom-category` then show second select box but when I deselect the `custom-category` not hide the second select box

Comment: oh you are right , i am not reseting the values on categoryFlag and tagFlag , try in the last section of if eles resetting the values, i ll update the anwser.

Comment: Thanks so much your code work perfectly. But I want before apply jquery `change()` function don't show second and third select boxes. But in your code before apply `change()` function shows second and third select boxes

Comment: sorry just saw now that you have said something, you can just start by hiding them in the beggining of your code, and that would solve the problem. 
like just calling 
   $('p.field-custom-category').hide();
    $('p.field-custom-tag').hide();

Comment: yes, I can do that. I hide the second and third select box before applying the change function until now not a problem. For example when I select the `custom-tag` directly show third select box but when I save the page then refresh it don't appear third select box? means only appear when to apply changes I want when to apply the change and selected `custom-tag` never hide the third  select box after save and refresh the page